# Laravel error Frame.php line 123at HandleExceptions

Tags: php, laravel

Need help  I am using framework Laravel 5.5 and everyday pretty  often showing up this kind of error.

This error showing up usually on different pages l cannot understand what is wrong and whats is it could be maybe I should renew Laravel? Maybe it's going to solve a problem? I cleaned cache tried a lot of type of anything rules file storage/framework/views everything correct. Could anyone please help me who has the same problem or any type of situation?

```
Frame.php line 123at HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'file_get_contents(/var/www/vhosts/*******/httpdocs/storage/framework/views/778d093ecf03c1c355a2d49e5e2d077704cd29d1.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory', '/var/www/vhosts//*******//httpdocs/vendor/filp/whoops/src/Whoops/Exception/Frame.php', 123, array('filePath' => '/var/www/vhosts/r/*******//httpdocs/storage/framework/views/778d093ecf03c1c355a2d49e5e2d077704cd29d1.php'))at file_get_contents('/var/www/vhosts//*******//httpdocs/storage/framework/views/778d093ecf03c1c355a2d49e5e2d077704cd29d1.php')in Frame.php line 123at Frame->getFileContents()in Frame.php line 203at Frame->getFileLines(173, 40)in frame_code.html.php line 24at require('/var/www/vhosts/r/*******//httpdocs/vendor/filp/whoops/src/Whoops/Resources/views/frame_code.html.php')in TemplateHelper.php line 250at TemplateHelper->Whoops\Util\{closure}('/var/www/vhosts/r/*******//httpdocs/vendor/filp/whoops/src/Whoops/Handler/../Resources/views/frame_code.html.php ……
```

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like a view cache error. Try to run

```
php artisan view:clear
php artisan view:cache
```

Comment: I have done this already, but it does not help, the error is still repeated

Answer (score 0):

The code does not have permission to create and edit files.
You need to go to the `httpdocs` directory and run the `sudo chmod 777 -R storage/` command there